# ArcGIS how to capture attribute data from another layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, line

I have an arc layer with points and another with lines. The points exist along the lines (as stations). Both layers have an attribute for LineName. How do I pass the specific line name data to the points layer?
In my specific example image, the LineName is displayed but the points table has empty LineName attributes, which are the ones I would like to populate.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways (at least) to achieve this:

1. [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000) the points to the lines, be sure to specify a
   distance. Even though you think the points are on the line in fact
   they're more likely to be just *very close*.
2. Use [Near](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001q000000) (advanced license) to get the FID of the line that the
   point is nearest then attribute [join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s0000002n000000) by NEAR_FID and field
   calculate the value.

Which one you pick depends on your license level and whether you want to change the existing data (adding new fields) or creating an output that has all the attributes of the lines embedded into the points. You can always [remove the fields](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004n000000) that are added when you're done to return your data into the original state.

Comment: Of course, you'll want to take a backup of your data before trying either of these ;)